# Drop shadow for text in PGF/Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, shadows

I want to *really* put an emphasis on some central piece of text I'm using in a Beamer slide.  I'm using tikz and overlay to put it, enlarged, on the center of the page, using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[at=(current page.center)] {
    \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{{This is important!}}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can I add a drop shadow to the letter themselves, so they would look even more emphasized?  Is there some other decoration that can be added to the text itself, like a glow, etc.?  Or does PGF ignores node text altogether?  The text should be in typewriter style, so using special fancy fonts is probably not the solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a terrible hack, and doesn't really fit your situation exactly, but I'm new to TeX and TikZ. Just an idea to get the ball rolling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\importantstuff[3]{
    \node[black!30!white] at (#1+0.1,#2-0.1) {
        \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1,#2) {
        \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    \importantstuff{4}{0}{This is important!}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: Marc van Dongen correctly pointed out I should use font-dependent offsets. And since I was fiddling with the code anyway, I tried blurring the shadow, hillbilly style.

```
\newcommand\importantstuff[3]{
    \newcommand\xoffset{0.3}
    \newcommand\yoffset{-0.2}
    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[black!20!white] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[black!40!white] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey Thanks, but I thought there may be a possibility to do something like `\node[important] {This is important}`. Also, I don't really know how to deal with `current page.center`.

Comment: It's a hack, but it works.  You can deal with `current page` by using the positioning library instead of `at` absolute positioning.

Comment: @Psirus Oh, it can *always* be packaged in a simpler way, (just wait until Ryan Reich turns up - then you'll see some `pgfkeys` magic), but *functionally* it would be the same as this.

Comment: @Psirus You code the offset in terms of centimetres. It would be nice if you did this in a unit that is defined in terms of the type size, e.g., em or ex. That way the shading will also look good when the type size changes.

Comment: A key to the node would be the ideal interface, but it seems pretty hard to implement.  To do it would require some hackery around `\tikz@do@fig` and a clever `\tikz@text@action` command.

Comment: @Andrew: Tempting!  But not today.

Answer (score 10):

@Psirus Your solution isn't what I had in mind. The following automatically picks up the *current* type size. In your solution the node is always `\Huge`. It's entirely based on your ideas, but I think it's a bit better to work with if you want different type sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\importantstuff[3]{
    \draw[every node/.style={scale=2}]
         (#1,#2)            coordinate (text destination)
      ++ (0.125em,-0.125em) coordinate (shadow destination)
         % Blur
         \foreach \x in {-0.025,0.025} {
             \foreach \y in {-0.025,0.025} {
                +(\x em,\y em) node[black!20!white] {\texttt{#3}}
             }
         }
        % Main Shadow
        (shadow destination) node[black!40!white] {\texttt{#3}}
        (text destination)   node {\texttt{#3}};
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \offset/\size in {0/Huge,1/small,2/normalsize} {
   \begin{\size}
       \importantstuff{0}{\offset}{This is important}
   \end{\size}}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I was half-aware of that :-) But I really didn’t know how to implement it. Thanks for showing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to emphasize your letters, you could try to produce paths
out of the glyphs in your text.  Either by converting the text to a path in a tool like `inkscape`.  Or you ask Andrew Stacey for his TikZ-path version of the STIX fonts.

Then you can use [`pgf-blur`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-blur) to add a pretty shadow:

[image: letters with blurred drop shadow]

But there's no way this will work directly with text typeset by TeX.