# Is there is a package so you can add text with visual effects like "WordArt" from "Word"

Tags: packages, diagrams, text-decorations, text-manipulation

I am elaborating a business card style for LaTeX but I found out that even if I have the style and margin for the cards I can not make it look "pretty" like other text editors without overusing text-images insertions, and this become tedious over time and more if you need to overlap an image to another one, because the background of the image needs to be transparent and it needs to be edited for that.

So like the title says, is there a package so you can add effects to sentences (like 3D, shadows, background-fade, fade, etc.)? Or does someone know some effects to make text "pretty"?

Comment: I guess a universal and general answer is `TikZ`

Comment: I would add 'pstricks' to the list of possibilities.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `pstricks`, we can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-light3d}
%http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-light3d/pst-light3d-doc.pdf

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\bigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1.5cm}
\pscharpath[linecolor=yellow,%
fillstyle=gradient,%
gradbegin=yellow,%
gradend=red,%
gradmidpoint=1,%
gradangle=5]%
{\bigsf PSTricks}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\nbigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1.3cm}
\psset{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red,gradend=blue}
\pscharpath[gradangle=90]{\nbigsf PSTricks}
\pscharpath[gradangle=90,linestyle=none]{\nbigsf PSTricks}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\Rmb}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{3cm}
\PstLightThreeDText[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow!100!red!70,
LightThreeDAngle=60,LightThreeDYLength=0.1]{\Rmb PSTricks}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! its nearly what i am looking for.
Theres a Documment where it explain about the "fillingstyle" options or advanced use for the package?

Comment: @Yaren Try www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-text and theory.stanford.edu/~sbansal/tut/latex/pstricks/chap9.pdf where I got the source for the example above. Note that you have to compile with `latex` or use `auto-pst-pdf` package to go directly into pdf with `--enable-write18` or `--shell-escape`.

Comment: Thanks so much! the second link give me a idea of how the package works.

Comment: @Yaren See my updated answer.

Comment: Thx for your time improving the answer, the second example helpme to see what to modify to make it change. cheers!

Comment: How can one compile this? I tried `sudo apt-get install -y texlive-pstricks` followed by `latex main.tex`, and `pdflatex --enable-write18 main.tex`, `xelatex main.tex` (as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93767), `f6` in Texmaker (yields `Undefined control sequence`), and compiling in overleaf, which also gives an error on `\bigsf`.

Answer (score 18):

As you can see, there are indeed ways to make text "pretty" using `TeX` and friends but they are definitely not *easy*. (This is actually one of the reasons why my WordArt-loving colleagues find it hard to switch to `LaTeX`. I, however, no longer use them due to my own opinions about WordArt:) As mentioned in the comments above, you can use graphical packages like `tikz` and `pstricks`.

A very nice `pstricks` example has already been provided by azetina but if you want to broaden your horizon, here are some posts in `tex.stack` that *might* help you.

- [Drop shadow for text in PGF/Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40853/drop-shadow-for-text-in-pgf-beamer)
- [Outlining (filling) glyph outline with text in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21548/outlining-filling-glyph-outline-with-text-in-tikz)
- [Convert font letters to vector format and fill with a pattern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58851/convert-font-letters-to-vector-format-and-fill-with-a-pattern)
- [Letterpress effect through PSTricks or Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62570/letterpress-effect-through-pstricks-or-tikz)
- External link: [Example: TikZ and PGF version 2.00](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-version-2/)

And here are some modified examples from the [`pgf` manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

### Code

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85863/is-there-is-a-package-so-you-can-add-text-with-visual-effects-like-wordart-fro
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
% First figure
\noindent
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
\node [text=transparent!20]
{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries\selectfont Ti\emph{k}Z};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[path fading=tikz,fit fading=false,
left color=blue,right color=black]
(-2,-1) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Second figure
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [decorate, decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={[}{]},text align=fit to path,
text={A big [\color{red}]red[] and [\color{green}]green[] apple.}}]
(0,0) .. controls (0,2) and (3,2) .. (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Here is my attempt at creating a WordArt-like command. You can tweak it so that you can also control the `xshift` and `yshift`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text}
\newcommand{\winarty}[5]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [xshift=2.5pt,yshift=-2pt,decorate, decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={[}{]},text align=fit to path,
text={[\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries\color{#4}\selectfont]#5[]}},]
(#1,0) .. controls (#1,0.75) and (#2,-0.75) .. (#2,0.5);

\path [decorate, decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={[}{]},text align=fit to path,
text={[\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries\color{#3}\selectfont]#5[]}},]
(#1,0) .. controls (#1,0.75) and (#2,-0.75) .. (#2,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\def\Exampletext{This is an example text.}
\winarty{1}{12}{blue!75!black}{gray}{\Exampletext}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to compile the MWE provided by Azetina, so tried some suggestions of Overleaf Templates, and answers to questions related to the terms in the comments to Azetina's answer. The following file named: `main.tex` can be compiled with:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex
```

And in Overleaf it can be compiled using the `latex` compiler (not `pdflatex`). The example is not minimal, but it works:

```
\def\jobname{main} % or whatever your main document .tex file is named!
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{Using PSTricks with pdflatex on Overleaf}
\author{Overleaf}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-light3d}
%http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-light3d/pst-light3d-doc.pdf


\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\bigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1.5cm}
\pscharpath[linecolor=yellow,%
fillstyle=gradient,%
gradbegin=yellow,%
gradend=red,%
gradmidpoint=1,%
gradangle=5]%
{\bigsf PSTricks}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\nbigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1.3cm}
\psset{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red,gradend=blue}
\pscharpath[gradangle=90]{\nbigsf PSTricks}
\pscharpath[gradangle=90,linestyle=none]{\nbigsf PSTricks}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\Rmb}{T1}{ptm}    {m}{n}{3cm}
\PstLightThreeDText[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow!100!red!70,
LightThreeDAngle=60,LightThreeDYLength=0.1]{\Rmb PSTricks}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Note

If you change the filename from `main.tex` to `something.tex`, you should change the first line of the file from:

```
\def\jobname{main} % or whatever your main document .tex file is named!
```

to:

```
\def\jobname{something} % or whatever your main document .tex file is named!
```