# PStricks does not show proper font and color

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I am learning to use PStricks. For that matter, I am trying to reproduce the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85866/77895) but I get a black word in standard font, without changes in style whatsoever. The only bit I can change is the text.

My code is (for the third example in the referred answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-light3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\Rmb}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{3cm}
\PstLightThreeDText[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!100!red!70,
LightThreeDAngle=60,LightThreeDYLength=0.1]{\Rmb Example}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

All I get is:

[image]

I am compiling with `xelatex` in TexStudio, using `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` as code.

The compilation message is:

```
Process started: xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode "test pstrick".tex

GPL Ghostscript

9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited normally
```

What is the problem?

Comment: it is only possible with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: @luconado: You can also compile with `xelatex`. Or you can compile with `pdflatex` if you load `auto-pst-pdf` (*after* `pstricks`)  and compile with the switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live MacTeX).

Comment: @Bernard: In this case you can _not_ compile with `xelatex`

Comment: @Herbert: You're perfectly right (as usual…). I should have tested this compiler – I only did so for pdflatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

[image]

There are some examples which will not work with the `xdvipdfmx` driver from `xelatex`